# How to edit .bst file to remove boldened volume no and remove colon?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{mybst}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file is

```
@article{zadeh1965,
    title = {Fuzzy sets},
journal = {Information and Control},
volume = {\textbf{8}},
number = {3},
pages = {338-353},
year = {1965},
issn = {0019-9958},
DOI = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0019-9958(65)90241-X",
author = {L.A. Zadeh}
}
```

This is my present `mybst.bst` file:

```
  ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
    { "~" }
    { " " }
  if$
  swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
 % Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
 % Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
 % The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "editors" }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "editor" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edition" }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "volume" }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "number" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "No." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pages" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "page" }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chapter" }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Technical Report" }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
 {"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      pop$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ pop$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
  duplicate$ missing$
    {
      swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
      ""
    }
    { duplicate$ empty$
        {
          swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
        }
        { swap$
          pop$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


STRINGS  { bibinfo}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  format.names
}
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  ""
  duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    {
      before.all 'output.state :=
    " (" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION{format.year}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {  "empty year in " cite$ *
       warning$
    }
    {
  "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { 

 "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          n.dashify
        }
        {
        }
      if$
      "pages" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ": " *
          format.year * " " *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      {
          ": " *
      }
      if$
      swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "volume" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      ", " bbl.nr * number tie.or.space.prefix pop$ * swap$ *
    }
  if$ *
  bolden
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          "," *
          " " *
          get.bbl.editor
          ", " *
          * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
  month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
  and and and and and
  key empty$ not and
    { "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  key duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$
      journal duplicate$ empty$
        { "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref * warning$ }
        { "journal" bibinfo.check emphasize word.in swap$ * }
      if$
    }
    { word.in swap$ * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  "editor" bibinfo.check
  editor num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      "editor" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.etal
      *
    }
    { #2 <
        'skip$
        { editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            {
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              " " * bbl.etal
              *
            }
            {
             bbl.and space.word
              * editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
              "editor" bibinfo.check
              *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      capitalize
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { series empty$
            { "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
              "" *
            }
            { series emphasize * }
          if$
        }
        { key * }
      if$
    }
    { format.crossref.editor * }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  editor empty$
  editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
  or
    { key empty$
        { format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$
            { "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
              crossref * warning$
            }
            { word.in swap$ * }
          if$
        }
        { word.in key * " " *}
      if$
    }
    { word.in format.crossref.editor * " " *}
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
      year empty$
        'skip$
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            'skip$
            { ", " swap$ * * }
          if$
          year "year" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
      format.edition output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.pages output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { output
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
      if$
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  author empty$
    { organization empty$
        {
          address new.block.checka
          address "address" bibinfo.check output
        }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
    {
      organization address new.block.checkb
      organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      address "address" bibinfo.check output
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  new.block
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title output
  howpublished new.block.checka
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  empty.misc.check
}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  new.block
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  editor empty$
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
    }
    { format.editors output.nonnull }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  editor empty$
    { publisher empty$
        'skip$
        {
          new.sentence
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
    }
    { publisher empty$
        {
          new.sentence
          format.organization.address output }
        {
          new.sentence
          organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
     }
  if$
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title
  "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.date output
  new.block
  format.note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" 't := }
            'skip$
          if$
          t sortify *
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {negate.year}
{ year empty$
    { "99999" }
    { year #1 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$
      year #2 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
      year #3 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
      year #4 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
    }
    if$
}
FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
    { organization empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { organization empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.organization.sort
        { type$ "manual" =
            'author.organization.sort
            'author.sort
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
  "    "
  *
  negate.year field.or.null sortify
  "    "
  *
  swap$ *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
ITERATE {presort}
SORT
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
  #1 'number.label :=
  #0 'longest.label.width :=
}
FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
  number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
  label width$ longest.label.width >
    { label 'longest.label :=
      label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
  write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

My output is:
[image]

But I need this format:
[image]

That is, I have:

> `journal name`, `page`, **No.5:** (1987)

and I need removal of bold in the number and `No.`, removal of colon (`:`) after the number, and removal of the comma between journal and page number. The result is:

> `journal name` `page`, No. 5 (1987)

I am completely new to this, how to change the .bst functions to get the desired output?

Comment: *A priori*, replace `volume = {\textbf{8}}` with `volume=8`.

Comment: in the bst, in `FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}`, remove the line that says `bolden`.

Comment: Besides Lupino solution, you can also edit `FUNCTION {bolden}` altering `"\textbf{" swap$ * "}"` removing between quotes and checking the syntax (I can't say if it will not give some error, I should test it, sorry). Editing the `FUNCTION {bolden}` will remove bold from every other kind of entry that calls this FUNCTION.

Comment: @Lupino It undoes bolden throughout, including volume, i.e 32 in the second fig... also the colon is not removed after the number.

Comment: @FHZ would really appreciate it to be elaborated into an answer, tried but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to proceed when you must edit an bst.

1. Keep calm and [Tame The BeaST](http://tug.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)
2. Read about RPN (Reverse Polish Notation)
3. Create a copy of the original bst
4. Don't be afraid ot insert any nonsense set of letters to find out what does what.

---

*MWE*

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{mybst}
\def\bibcommenthead{}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliography{test.bib}
\end{document}
```

And let me use the same *test.bib* I used [in this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/654401/140133), with your reference `zadeh1965`.

#### Let's Tame the BeaST

Basic we are editing functions called by the function `FUNCTION {article}`, starting at line 857, or functions called by that function and so on.

The original result is:

[image]

---

For reference, the first line is the line with `ENTRY`. I'll present the line and respective `FUNCTION`, then the line and original content to be changed and the new content.

**Changing bold for all**

Line 155: `FUNCTION {bolden}`

Change line 158: `{ "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }`
into: `{ "{" swap$ * "}" * }`.

[image]

---

**colon**

Line 601: `FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}`

Change line 606: `": " *`
into: `" " *`

[image]

---

**comma**

Now let's finish removing the comma between journal and volume number.

Line 36: `FUNCTION {output.nonnull}`
Change line 39: `{ ", " * write$ }`
into: `{ " " * write$ }`

[image]

---

Comment: @S.S., please let me know if you could perform the editions I propose and these editions had the effect the pictures show. Any doubts, don't hesitate in asking for clarifications.

Comment: from their answer to my comment, i believe that the OP wants the volume field to still be bold-faced, so redefining the BOLDEN macro goes a bit too far, imo.

Comment: @FHZ  thanks a ton for your answer, took idea to further replace the dots by commas after author name and title in zadeh1965, also I emboldened the volume field. patting myself!

Comment: @S.S., oh, I'm totally sorry about where should and should not be bold, I removed `\textbf` from bolden, so all bolds are not applied. To apply for a subset of entry types, remove where function `bolden` is called.

Comment: @FHZ hey could you also help answering this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/666492/swapping-the-volume-number-and-year-in-bst-file

Comment: S.S, I will take a look until next weekend.