# Swapping the volume number and year in .bst file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle, bst, customize

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{mybst}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

My `.bib` file is

```
@article{liberti2009,
 title={Class of self-concordant functions on Riemannian manifolds},
 author={G. Bercu and M. Postolache},
journal={Balkan J. Geom. Appl},
volume={14},
number={01},
pages={1--18},
year={2009},

}
```

I have successfully edited some parts of the `mybst.bst` file...

```
% ====================== mybst.BST ================ %
```

%%
%% This is file `punjab.bst', %% generated with the docstrip utility. %% %% The original source files were: %% %% merlin.mbs  (with options:` seq-yrr,nm-init,ed-au,yr-par,xmth,tit-it,jttl-rm,vol-2bf,vnum-nr,volp-sp,jdt-p,num-xser,bkpg-x,pub-date,pub-xpar,xedn,and-xcom,nfss,')
%% ----------------------------------------
%% *** this is bibstyle created by shatabdi ***
%%
%% Copyright 1994-2011 Patrick W Daly
% ===============================================================
% IMPORTANT NOTICE:
% This bibliographic style (bst) file has been generated from one or
% more master bibliographic style (mbs) files, listed above.
%
% This generated file can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN
% archives in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt; either
% version 1 of the License, or any later version.
% ===============================================================
% Name and version information of the main mbs file:
% \ProvidesFile{merlin.mbs}[2011/11/18 4.33 (PWD, AO, DPC)]
%   For use with BibTeX version 0.99a or later
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
% This is a numerical citation style, and as such is standard LaTeX.
% It requires no extra package to interface to the main text.
% The form of the \bibitem entries is
%   \bibitem{key}...
% Usage of \cite is as follows:
%   \cite{key} ==>>          [#]
%   \cite[chap. 2]{key} ==>> [#, chap. 2]
% where # is a number determined by the ordering in the reference list.
% The order in the reference list is alphabetical by authors.
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

ENTRY
{ address
author
booktitle
chapter
edition
editor
eid
howpublished
institution
journal
key
month
note
number
organization
pages
publisher
school
series
title
type
volume
year
}
{}
{ label }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
#1 'mid.sentence :=
#2 'after.sentence :=
#3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
output.state mid.sentence =
{ " " * write$ }
{ output.state after.block =
{ add.period$ write$
newline$
"\newblock " write$
}
{ output.state before.all =
'write$
{ add.period$ " " * write$ }
if$
}
if$
mid.sentence 'output.state :=
}
if$
s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
'pop$
'output.nonnull
if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
'output.nonnull
if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
write$
newline$
}

FUNCTION {my.new.block}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ skip$ }
{
", " * }
if$
before.all 'output.state :=
new.block
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
'skip$
{ after.block 'output.state := }
if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
'skip$
{ output.state before.all =
'skip$
{ after.sentence 'output.state := }
if$
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
new.block
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
{ #1 }
if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
{ pop$ #0 }
if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
'skip$
if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
'skip$
'new.block
if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
swap$ empty$
and
'skip$
'new.block
if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
'skip$
'new.sentence
if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
swap$ empty$
and
'skip$
'new.sentence
if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
'skip$
if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "" }
{ "{ " swap$ * "}" * }
if$
}
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3 <
{ "~" }
{ " " }
if$
swap$
}

FUNCTION {capitalize}
{ "u" change.case$ "t" change.case$ }

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }
% Here are the language-specific definitions for explicit words.
% Each function has a name bbl.xxx where xxx is the English word.
% The language selected here is ENGLISH
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}
{ "et~al." }

FUNCTION {bbl.editors}
{ "editors" }

FUNCTION {bbl.editor}
{ "editor" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}
{ "edited by" }

FUNCTION {bbl.edition}
{ "edition" }

FUNCTION {bbl.volume}
{ "volume" }

FUNCTION {bbl.of}
{ "of" }

FUNCTION {bbl.number}
{ "number" }

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}
{ "No." }

FUNCTION {bbl.in}
{ "in" }

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}
{ "pages" }

FUNCTION {bbl.page}
{ "page" }

FUNCTION {bbl.chapter}
{ "chapter" }

FUNCTION {bbl.techrep}
{ "Technical Report" }

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ "Master's thesis" }

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ "Ph.D. thesis" }

MACRO {jan} {"January"}

MACRO {feb} {"February"}

MACRO {mar} {"March"}

MACRO {apr} {"April"}

MACRO {may} {"May"}

MACRO {jun} {"June"}

MACRO {jul} {"July"}

MACRO {aug} {"August"}

MACRO {sep} {"September"}

MACRO {oct} {"October"}

MACRO {nov} {"November"}

MACRO {dec} {"December"}

MACRO {acmcs} {"ACM Computing Surveys"}

MACRO {acta} {"Acta Informatica"}

MACRO {cacm} {"Communications of the ACM"}

MACRO {ibmjrd} {"IBM Journal of Research and Development"}

MACRO {ibmsj} {"IBM Systems Journal"}

MACRO {ieeese} {"IEEE Transactions on Software Engineering"}

MACRO {ieeetc} {"IEEE Transactions on Computers"}

MACRO {ieeetcad}
{"IEEE Transactions on Computer-Aided Design of Integrated Circuits"}

MACRO {ipl} {"Information Processing Letters"}

MACRO {jacm} {"Journal of the ACM"}

MACRO {jcss} {"Journal of Computer and System Sciences"}

MACRO {scp} {"Science of Computer Programming"}

MACRO {sicomp} {"SIAM Journal on Computing"}

MACRO {tocs} {"ACM Transactions on Computer Systems"}

MACRO {tods} {"ACM Transactions on Database Systems"}

MACRO {tog} {"ACM Transactions on Graphics"}

MACRO {toms} {"ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software"}

MACRO {toois} {"ACM Transactions on Office Information Systems"}

MACRO {toplas} {"ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems"}

MACRO {tcs} {"Theoretical Computer Science"}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
{ swap$
duplicate$ missing$
{
pop$ pop$
""
}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{
swap$ pop$
}
{ swap$
pop$
}
if$
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {bibinfo.warn}
{ swap$
duplicate$ missing$
{
swap$ "missing " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$ pop$
""
}
{ duplicate$ empty$
{
swap$ "empty " swap$ * " in " * cite$ * warning$
}
{ swap$
pop$
}
if$
}
if$
}
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

STRINGS  { bibinfo}

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
's :=
"" 't :=
#1 'nameptr :=
s num.names$ 'numnames :=
numnames 'namesleft :=
{ namesleft #0 > }
{ s nameptr
"{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
format.name$
bibinfo bibinfo.check
't :=
nameptr #1 >
{
namesleft #1 >
{ ", " * t * }
{
s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
{ 't := }
{ pop$ }
if$
t "others" =
{
" " * bbl.etal *
}
{
bbl.and
space.word * t *
}
if$
}
if$
}
't
if$
nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=

```
}
```

while$
} if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
format.names
}
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
"," *
" " *
get.bbl.editor
*
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
note empty$
{ "" }
{ note #1 #1 substring$
duplicate$ "{" =
'skip$
{ output.state mid.sentence =
{ "l" }
{ "u" }
if$
change.case$
}
if$
note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
}
if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{ "t" change.case$ }
if$
"title" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
emphasize
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
"\bibitem{" write$
cite$ write$
"}" write$
newline$
""
before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
't :=
""
{ t empty$ not }
{ t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
{ t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
{ "--" *
t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
}
{   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
{ "-" *
t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
}
while$
}
if$
}
{ t #1 #1 substring$ *
t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
}
if$
}
while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
" " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{
""
duplicate$ empty$
year  "year"  bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
{ swap$ 'skip$
{ "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
if$
*
}
{ swap$ 'skip$
{
swap$
" " * swap$
}
if$
*
}
if$
duplicate$ empty$
'skip$
{
before.all 'output.state :=
" (" swap$ * ")" *
}
if$
}
FUNCTION{format.year}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
{  "empty year in " cite$ *
warning$
}
{
"(" swap$ * ")" *
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
emphasize
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
'pop$
{ "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
{ "" }
{ bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
"volume" bibinfo.check * *
series "series" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$
'pop$
{ "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * ", " * swap$ * }
if$
"volume and number" number either.or.check
}

if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
{ number empty$
{ series field.or.null }
{ series empty$
{ number "number" bibinfo.check }
{ output.state mid.sentence =
{ bbl.number }
{ bbl.number capitalize }
if$
number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
bbl.in space.word *
series "series" bibinfo.check *
}
if$
}
if$
}
{ "" }
if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
output.state mid.sentence =
{ "l" }
{ "t" }
if$ change.case$
"edition" bibinfo.check
" " * bbl.edition *
}
if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
#0 'multiresult :=
{ multiresult not
t empty$ not
and
}
{ t #1 #1 substring$
duplicate$ "-" =
swap$ duplicate$ "," =
swap$ "+" =
or or
{ #1 'multiresult := }
{ t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
if$
}
while$
multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{ duplicate$ multi.page.check
{
n.dashify
}
{
}
if$
"pages" bibinfo.check
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
{ swap$ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ pop$ format.pages }
{
" " *
format.year * " " *
swap$
n.dashify
"pages" bibinfo.check
*
}
if$
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
{ swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
": " *
}
if$
swap$ *
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ "{\bfseries " volume "}" * * field.or.null

duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
"volume" bibinfo.check
}
if$
number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
swap$ duplicate$ empty$
{ "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
'skip$
if$
swap$
", " bbl.nr * number tie.or.space.prefix pop$ * swap$ *
}
if$ *
bolden
eid empty$
{ format.journal.pages }
{ format.journal.eid }
if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
'format.pages
{ type empty$
{ bbl.chapter }
{ type "l" change.case$
"type" bibinfo.check
}
if$
chapter tie.or.space.prefix
"chapter" bibinfo.check
* *
pages empty$
'skip$
{ ", " * format.pages * }
if$
}
if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
{
editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
{
"," *
" " *
get.bbl.editor
", " *
* swap$
* }
if$
word.in swap$ *
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {empty.misc.check}
{ author empty$ title empty$ howpublished empty$
month empty$ year empty$ note empty$
and and and and and
key empty$ not and
{ "all relevant fields are empty in " cite$ * warning$ }
'skip$
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
'pop$
{ swap$ pop$
"t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
type duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ bbl.techrep }
'skip$
if$
"type" bibinfo.check
swap$ duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$ "t" change.case$ }
{ tie.or.space.prefix * * }
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
key duplicate$ empty$
{ pop$
journal duplicate$ empty$
{ "need key or journal for " cite$ * " to crossref " * crossref * warning$ }
{ "journal" bibinfo.check emphasize word.in swap$ * }
if$
}
{ word.in swap$ * " " *}
if$
" \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.crossref.editor}
{ editor #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
"editor" bibinfo.check
editor num.names$ duplicate$
#2 >
{ pop$
"editor" bibinfo.check
" " * bbl.etal
*
}
{ #2 <
'skip$
{ editor #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
{
"editor" bibinfo.check
" " * bbl.etal
*
}
{
bbl.and space.word
* editor #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
"editor" bibinfo.check
*
}
if$
}
if$
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
{ "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
pop$ word.in
}
{ bbl.volume
capitalize
swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
}
if$
editor empty$
editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
or
{ key empty$
{ series empty$
{ "need editor, key, or series for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
crossref * warning$
"" *
}
{ series emphasize * }
if$
}
{ key * }
if$
}
{ format.crossref.editor * }
if$
" \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
editor empty$
editor field.or.null author field.or.null =
or
{ key empty$
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$
{ "need editor, key, or booktitle for " cite$ * " to crossref " *
crossref * warning$
}
{ word.in swap$ * }
if$
}
{ word.in key * " " *}
if$
}
{ word.in format.crossref.editor * " " *}
if$
" \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
""
year empty$
{ "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
'skip$
if$
address empty$ t empty$ and
year empty$ and
'skip$
{
t empty$
{ address "address" bibinfo.check *
}
{ t *
address empty$
'skip$
{ ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
if$
}
if$
year empty$
'skip$
{ t empty$ address empty$ and
'skip$
{ ", " swap$ * * }
if$
year "year" bibinfo.check
*
}
if$
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.title "title" output.check
new.block
crossref missing$
{
journal
"journal" bibinfo.check
"journal" output.check
format.vol.num.pages output
}
{ format.article.crossref output.nonnull
format.pages output
}
if$
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
author empty$
{ format.editors "author and editor" output.check
}
{ format.authors output.nonnull
crossref missing$
{ "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
'skip$
if$
}
if$
new.block
format.btitle "title" output.check
crossref missing$
{ format.bvolume output
new.block
format.number.series output
new.sentence
format.publisher.address output
}
{
new.block
format.book.crossref output.nonnull
format.date "year" output.check
}
if$
format.edition output
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors output
my.new.block
format.title "title" output.check
new.block
howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
address "address" bibinfo.check output
format.date output
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
author empty$
{ format.editors "author and editor" output.check
}
{ format.authors output.nonnull
crossref missing$
{ "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
'skip$
if$
}
if$
new.block
format.btitle "title" output.check
crossref missing$
{
format.bvolume output
format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
new.block
format.number.series output
new.sentence
format.publisher.address output
}
{
format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
new.block
format.book.crossref output.nonnull
format.date "year" output.check
}
if$
format.edition output
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.title "title" output.check
new.block
crossref missing$
{ format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
format.bvolume output
format.number.series output
format.chapter.pages output
new.sentence
format.publisher.address output
format.edition output
}
{ format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
format.chapter.pages output
}
if$
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.title "title" output.check
new.block
crossref missing$
{ format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
format.bvolume output
format.number.series output
format.pages output
new.sentence
publisher empty$
{ format.organization.address output }
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
format.publisher.address output
}
if$
}
{ format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
format.pages output
}
if$
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
author empty$
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check
duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
{ output
address "address" bibinfo.check output
}
if$
}
{ format.authors output.nonnull }
if$
new.block
format.btitle "title" output.check
author empty$
{ organization empty$
{
address new.block.checka
address "address" bibinfo.check output
}
'skip$
if$
}
{
organization address new.block.checkb
organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
address "address" bibinfo.check output
}
if$
format.edition output
format.date output
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.btitle
"title" output.check
new.block
bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
school "school" bibinfo.warn output
address "address" bibinfo.check output
format.date "year" output.check
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors output
title howpublished new.block.checkb
format.title output
howpublished new.block.checka
howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
format.date output
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
empty.misc.check
}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.btitle
"title" output.check
new.block
bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
school "school" bibinfo.warn output
address "address" bibinfo.check output
format.date "year" output.check
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
editor empty$
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
}
{ format.editors output.nonnull }
if$
new.block
format.btitle "title" output.check
format.bvolume output
format.number.series output
editor empty$
{ publisher empty$
'skip$
{
new.sentence
format.publisher.address output
}
if$
}
{ publisher empty$
{
new.sentence
format.organization.address output }
{
new.sentence
organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
format.publisher.address output
}
if$
}
if$
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.title
"title" output.check
new.block
format.tr.number output.nonnull
institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
address "address" bibinfo.check output
format.date "year" output.check
new.block
format.note output
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
format.authors "author" output.check
my.new.block
format.title "title" output.check
format.date output
new.block
format.note "note" output.check
fin.entry
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
"l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
'len :=
s #1 len substring$ =
{ s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
's
if$
}
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
#1 'nameptr :=
""
s num.names$ 'numnames :=
numnames 'namesleft :=
{ namesleft #0 > }
{ s nameptr
"{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
format.name$ 't :=
nameptr #1 >
{
"   "  *
namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
{ "zzzzz" 't := }
'skip$
if$
t sortify *
}
{ t sortify * }
if$
nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
}
while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
"A " #2
"An " #3
"The " #4 t chop.word
chop.word
chop.word
sortify
#1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
{ key empty$
{ "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
""
}
{ key sortify }
if$
}
{ author sort.format.names }
if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
{ editor empty$
{ key empty$
{ "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
""
}
{ key sortify }
if$
}
{ editor sort.format.names }
if$
}
{ author sort.format.names }
if$
}
FUNCTION {negate.year}
{ year empty$
{ "99999" }
{ year #1 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$
year #2 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
year #3 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
year #4 #1 substring$ chr.to.int$ #105 swap$ - int.to.chr$ *
}
if$
}
FUNCTION {author.organization.sort}
{ author empty$
{ organization empty$
{ key empty$
{ "to sort, need author, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
""
}
{ key sortify }
if$
}
{ "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
if$
}
{ author sort.format.names }
if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.organization.sort}
{ editor empty$
{ organization empty$
{ key empty$
{ "to sort, need editor, organization, or key in " cite$ * warning$
""
}
{ key sortify }
if$
}
{ "The " #4 organization chop.word sortify }
if$
}
{ editor sort.format.names }
if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ type$ "book" =
type$ "inbook" =
or
'author.editor.sort
{ type$ "proceedings" =
'editor.organization.sort
{ type$ "manual" =
'author.organization.sort
'author.sort
if$
}
if$
}
if$
"    "
*
negate.year field.or.null sortify
"    "
*
swap$ *
title field.or.null
sort.format.title
*
#1 entry.max$ substring$
'sort.key$ :=
}
ITERATE {presort}
SORT
STRINGS { longest.label }
INTEGERS { number.label longest.label.width }
FUNCTION {initialize.longest.label}
{ "" 'longest.label :=
#1 'number.label :=
#0 'longest.label.width :=
}
FUNCTION {longest.label.pass}
{ number.label int.to.str$ 'label :=
number.label #1 + 'number.label :=
label width$ longest.label.width >
{ label 'longest.label :=
label width$ 'longest.label.width :=
}
'skip$
if$
}
EXECUTE {initialize.longest.label}
ITERATE {longest.label.pass}
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
'skip$
{ preamble$ write$ newline$ }
if$
"\begin{thebibliography}{"  longest.label  * "}" *
write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
"\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}

```
EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

I need 1 but my output is [2]

[image]

`How to change the .bst functions to get the desired output?`

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you would like to have as a result, or how should it be? Do you mean with "`need 1 but my output is [2]`" that you'd like the reference to be presented only once, but it is actually printed twice?

Comment: Could you please save your `.bst` file and give access to it? As it is written, it is not well formatted and it makes much more difficult to edit anything on the file.